# Ajax loading html onto page and using page js not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build my own Javascript modal. The problem I'm having is I'm using ajax to load the html and append to the modal on the page. However by doing this the javascript doesn't run inside the modal:

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    method: 'GET',
    async: true,
    success: Delegate.create(this, function(data) {
        $.getScript("/public/js/main.js");
        return $(this.$modal).append(data);
    })
});
```

When the request is made the script appends the html that I have loaded to the modal. My problem is that the html that im appending to the page contains a form which I then need to validate with javascript. However javascript doesn't work on the html i have loaded into the modal.

Any ideas on how I could potentially fix this?

I have tried using `$.getScript()` but then the script is running twice on the page.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Any JS needs to execute in the parent page, not loaded page. So bring that js over to parent and run the function after your ajax is successful.

Answer (score 1):

You r problem is that the main page JS has loaded and executed so once there is nothing to bind to.  So on the success perhaps add a function call to then init the forms js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    method: 'GET',
    async: true,
    success:function(data) {
        $(this.$modal).append(data);

        //-- call the form js
        theFormData();
    })
});

function theFormData(){
    //-- add your code here, this should now be able to bind to your form as it 
    //-- has something to hook onto
}
```

This type of thing....